# Azure log analytics and Azure AD Sign-in logs

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have imported Azure AD Sign-in logs to LogAnalytics workspace.
I like to create a web portal where user input some data like user name, Date and time. Based on the user data the web portal should retrieve data from Azure Log Analytics and present it in table format on the web portal.
Any suggestions how can I achieve this?
I can run queries on Azur LogAnalytics to retrieve the data but I like to do the same from a web portal.

In simple words, I like to use a Front end for user input(User name and Date filed) run a log analytics query to retrieve data based on user input data and then present the query result in table format. I've attached a picture to explain what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Attached PIC]

Comment: You'd better providing some screenshots, then people can easily understand / resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to request the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns` to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing for the benefit of broader audience - Related question is being responded and followed-up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/63587/index.html) in Microsoft Q&A platform.

In other words, one way to accomplish your requirement is by creating a light weighted [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/get-started/web-app/)  / [Azure Function App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/#get-started) for web portal which basically would be a single-page web application that queries [Log Analytics Get Query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get) and displays the query results on the page.

Related references:

1. [Log Analytics Get Query PowerShell Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/invoke-azoperationalinsightsquery?view=azps-4.5.0)
2. [Log Analytics Get Query CLI Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/log-analytics/monitor/log-analytics?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-log-analytics-az-monitor-log-analytics-query)
3. [Static Web Apps single page hosting option available in App Service now in preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/static-web-apps-single-page-hosting-option-available-in-app-service-now-in-preview/)
4. [Publish an Angular, React, Svelte, or Vue JavaScript app and API with Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/publish-app-service-static-web-app-api/?WT.mc_id=build2020_swa-frameworks-cxa)
5. [Simple branded website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/solutions/architecture/simple-branded-website/)
6. [Azure solution architectures - App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/solutions/architecture/?product=app-service)
7. [Single-page web app reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/tutorial-bing-news-search-single-page-app)